# Running mean.js using docker-compose fails

Tags: javascript, sass, mean, boot2docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run a clear mean.js project inside a docker container but I am facing an error during the start of the container (build was successful):

```
web_1 | Running "env:dev" (env) task
web_1 | 
web_1 | Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
web_1 | Warning: 
web_1 | You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work.
web_1 | More info: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass
web_1 |  Use --force to continue.
web_1 |
```

To run the project locally I had to manually install sass, but how do I setup sass for the docker container? Shouldn't mean.js and docker work out of the box? The documentation said nothing about installing sass at all, so did I make a mistake?

I am using:

- mean.js: 0.4.0
- Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.7.1
- docker-compose version: 1.3.3
- CPython version: 2.7.9
- OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014

Comment: Did you try searching for the exact error you got?

Comment: @cimmanon the process stopped because of the warning i posted: 

    web_1 | Running "env:dev" (env) task web_1 | web_1 | Running  "sass:dist" (sass) task web_1 | Warning: web_1 | You need to have Ruby and Sass installed and in your PATH for this task to work. web_1 | More info: github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass web_1 | Use --force to continue. web_1 | web_1 | Aborted due to warnings. whizperme_web_1 exited with code 6 –

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.  Did you try using a search engine and typing in the exact error you received to see if someone else had this problem?  You're expected to do basic research/debugging *before* you ask questions.

Comment: @cimmanon sry, I misunderstood your question. Of course I did research before I posted this question. I found solutions how to fix this issue for local maschines but with docker this would end up installing sass manually for each docker container.

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by using the mean.js "master" branch instead of using the "0.4.0" branch. This version is using "--force" to continue the grunt process after this warning.